# How to fix System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format'

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to change Font Family in VB.NET for a RichTextBox

I have tried searching through google and even specific sites for just code problems. Nothing works.

These are the codes for FontFamily changing (it is a tool strip combo button)

```
Private Sub TscFontFamily_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tscFontFamily.TextChanged
        rtbContent.SelectionFont = New Font(Convert.ToString(tscFontFamily.Text), Convert.ToInt32(tscFontSize.Text))
    End Sub
```

And the FontSize (also a tool strip combo button)

```
 Private Sub tscFontSize_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tscFontSize.TextChanged
        Dim newSize As Single = Convert.ToSingle(tscFontSize.Text)
        rtbContent.SelectionFont = New Font(rtbContent.SelectionFont.FontFamily, newSize)
    End Sub
```

I expect this to work since it makes sense, right? But it says "input string was not in correct format" and if i remove the Convert.ToString and other convert code, it says something like "Conversion from string "" to type 'Single' is not valid.".

Also to mentiion, is the fact that i have actually tried Convert.ToString and Convert.ToDouble and basically everything for BOTH.

Comment: Did you tag [tag:VBA] by accident, or are you looking for answers to both VBA and VB.Net, because I don't see any VBA here?

Comment: If you have this error then the content of _tscFontSize.Text_ cannot be converted to an Integer or Double or Single. What is the content of that TextBox? Keep in mind that the TextChanged event will be called for each character you type. Even when you have not yet finished to input your text

Comment: Well Nacorid yes i did i am so sorry i though vba and vb.net was the same thing xD

Comment: the content or value of the fontsize textbox is for instance "11" or "8" or you know font sizes

Comment: Why not just use a Font DialogBox? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-show-a-font-list-with-the-fontdialog-component

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to call ToString on `tscFontFamily.Text` because the Text property of a TextBox returns a String; you're essentially saying return a String value from this String value.

Convert.ToInt32 is a quick and dirty was of converting String values to Int32 (aka integer) values. If you're relying on input from a user then you should almost always use Int32.TryParse instead. This method returns a Boolean value based on if the conversion of the input is successful and then the second parameter passed is a reference variable so if the result of the method is True then the second parameter contains the converted value. However, it looks like you're wanting a Single value in which case you'd actually use Single.TryParse.

Here would be an example applying the changes to your code:

```
Private Sub tscFontSize_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tscFontSize.TextChanged
    Dim newSize As Single
    If Single.TryParse(tscFontSize.Text, newSize) Then
        rtbContent.SelectionFont = New Font(rtbContent.SelectionFont.FontFamily, newSize)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay thanks, but sadly the code did not work, i still have the whole 'rtbContent.SelectionFont = New Font(tscFontFamily.Text, tscFontSize.Text)' after i added that code to the tscFontSize Sub, will i have to add this tryparse code to the FrontFamily code to? and if so should i use String?

Comment: @JamieEngel Yes and no. Yes,  add the .TryParse code to the other Sub for the font size. No, the .Text property is a string and does not need to be converted.